# How to make string/variables from query results into a link in php

Tags: php, string

best regards.

I know perhaps some's considering my question is quite stupido. But I've been trying looking for to this simple scripting. As my post title above, how to make the query results into a url. I have this scripts:

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,'SELECT......');

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Author</th>
<th>Publisher</th>
<th>Category</th>
<th>Link</th>
</tr>";

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['author_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['publisher_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['cat_name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['url_flipbook'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "</table>";
```

I want to make the result from $row ->'url_flipbook' into a url. The $row -> 'url_flipbook' will produce a html pages that users can click on it, it's located to a folder in my localhost.

The database field:

```
| url_flipbook |
-----------------
/myspace/click-it/info_1.html
```

I want that query results became a link for the output.
I've tried:

```
<a href=''echo $row['url_flipbook'];'?>''>FLIPBOOK</a>"</td>";
echo "<td>" . <a href='$row['url_flipbook']>FLIPBOOK</a>"</td>";
```

Nothing works...if you could help me to solve this problems. Thank you so much...
best regards,

Kris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just concat the string to the `href`:

```
echo "<td><a href=\"" . $row['url_flipbook'] . "\">FLIPBOOK</a></td>";
```

or alternatively:

```
echo '<td><a href="' . $row['url_flipbook'] . '">FLIPBOOK</a></td>';
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it works :) cheers....I've red some posts about using the backslash operators, but all make me confused because most of the examples advising using '_SERVER[$...]' . Thank you so much h2ooooooo for the fast responses. I'm sorry cannot give you point to 'useful' answer because less of my reputation point.

Comment: @Kris The backslashes aren't operators - they escape whatever comes after them. If you use a `'` inside a string created by `'`, you have to escape it to `\'`. Likewise, if you want to use `"`'s inside a string created by `"`'s, you have to escape to `\"`. `echo "'"` is a single quote in double quotes, `echo '"'` is a double quote in single quotes, `echo '\''` is a single quote in single quotes and `echo "\""` is a double quote in double quotes.

Comment: @Kris It should also be noted that you can accept answers after 15 minutes (I think) when you've got low rep.

Comment: Wow...thanks again, sometimes it make me confused between the " " and the ' ' signs. I've learned a lot less than in 30 minutes...great :) I'll remembered it well, thanks again h2ooooooo

Answer (score 0):

did u try

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='" . $row['url_flipbook'] . "' >FLIPBOOK</a></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
echo "<td><a href='".$row['url_flipbook']."'>FLIPBOOK</a></td> ";
```

Comment: It works well too...Thanks echo_Me, I get a lot scripts knowledges today...fiuhh... :), best regards...